# nginx cache always return X-Proxy-Cache: MISS

Tags: caching, nginx

I config my `nginx` as follow:

```
proxy_cache_path /v01/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    charset utf-8;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        proxy_cache my_zone;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

I config with this in one machine which install `nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`, I test with:

```
 curl -X GET -I 192.168.1.193/css/style.css
```

it works, with head `X-Proxy-Cache: HIT`.

But I config with this in another machine which install `nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)`, `curl -X GET -I 192.168.1.97/css/style.css` always return `X-Proxy-Cache: MISS`.

I have check the path `/v01/nginx`, it has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have find where problem is:

I do not set node.js cache in my project in another machine, I change

```
 app.use express.static config.root + '/public'
```

to

```
 app.use express.static config.root + '/public', {maxAge: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7}
```